# How to rename git root folder?

Tags: git, directory, rename

I've just started using git in Vista, with my repository under `/path/to/project/git repo`.

I've now found that the space in the folder name is a minor irritation when working in git bash.

Can I just rename the folder to `/path/to/project/gitrepo`? Is everything within the git config relative, or is there anything that explicitly refers to the parent folder?

I've tried just taking a windows copy of the main folder, and run git bash on that, and 'git log' shows the changes I had previously made. So I assume renaming the main folder is OK, but I'd like to be sure before I go any further.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To amend slightly [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199659/rename-git-root-folder/7199670#7199670), yes, everything with a git repo is relative to the `.git` parent directory, but:

(and this won't probably affect you directly, I only mention those reasons here for completeness' sake.):

- the path of the repo itself could be referenced by other services running on your computer (Apache, ssh, another repo declaring your repo as a remote, using the full file path, a [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) layer declaring your repos in a certain path, ...)
- some operations use the full path of the repo (like the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` using within a `filter-branch` command for instance, see [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Problem-using-git-filter-branch-to-move-tree-when-repository-name-contains-space-td6231203.html)), so, obviously, don't rename the root directory while performing a complex operation on your repo.

Plus, a "windows copy" (instead of a `git clone`), will copy everything including hooks, which may include absolute path in their script if you have edited them and made those kind of modification.

Comment: so if anyone has practical, explicit steps to make sure to do, that would be very actionable.

Comment: @gwho what step, beside renaming the repo folder?

Answer (score 110):

Yes, it is safe to rename the folder containing a Git repository. All paths inside the Git repository are relative.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can change it. your repo still direct to your git.. just do not remove/edit name of .git fo