# How to rename git root folder hold by TGitCache under windows

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

Goal is to rename git root folder. 
Thread [How to rename git root folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199659/rename-git-root-folder) mentions it's safe to do so, but I cannot as TGitCache.exe holds the folder.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply terminate TGitCache.exe, as far as I know there is no harm in doing so and it will restart itself.

Comment: No issue killing TGitCache till now. I could rename my directory. Later, I could check a new instance of TGitCache.exe was holding the new directory.