# Can I rename a local folder which contains folders (& files) cloned from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

So I want to rename a (parent) folder on my laptop without disrupting the GitHub links between files & folders in this folder.

Is there anything special I need to do? Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, each git repository has a `.git` folder where everything git related is stored. Git only knows about files in that same folder and each one below that.

Possible duplicate: [How to rename git root folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199659/rename-git-root-folder)